# Windows Search Service (FS-search-server) gone on Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am converting a Windows Server 2008 R2 MDT installation to Server 2016.  One of the roles that we installed on 2008 was `Windows Search Service`, short name `FS-Search-Service`.  On Server 2016, doing a `Get-WindowsFeature FS* shows that it's not there.  I also noticed Windows Search service was disabled by default on my test machine, although I am still able to search, so I'm not entirely sure what this role is for, but I'm hoping I can get some clarification on this.  I don't have easy access to a Server 2012 machine to check.

Did they just take the role out for Server 2016 and include the service by default? Last question, out of curiosity, if the service is disabled, why does search seem to work just fine?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the role was renamed from `FS-Search-Service` to `Search-Service`, so that answers that question.

I'm still wondering what that service actually does though, because search seems to work just fine without it.  This page isn't super helpful:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Apparently, [that service is required to let clients access the search index](https://www.cloudtec.ch/blog/tech/2015/add-search-indexed-network-share-windows-library), for example, for searching on a network share. Unfortunately, I have not found any good MS sources describing this feature and its configuration (only third-party websites).